# Ganache doesn't connect to the network

Tags: blockchain, wsl-2, nft, ganache

I have been developing smart contracts with Ganache and Solidity. Where everyting worked well in the beginning I'm now not seeing any hosts to connect to anymore, it just gives me the image below and that's it, there are also no other options. I am developing on Windows WSL2 so before today I used to select something like 192.....1 but now it just won't give me that option anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer on the Ethereum Stackoverflow, for anyone interested:

*I tried something that worked for me -
if on windows, close ganache, head to %appdata% and then delete the Ganache folder.
Restart ganache and it should work as before from here..*

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102410/ganache-server-hostname-dropdown-not-displaying-all-hostnames